# Objective-C why need __NSGlobalBlock__

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

If my block don't capture variables I get `__NSGlobalBlock__`.

```
Class class = [^{
} class];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(class));
```

But if I capture variables I get `__NSStackBlock__`

```
int foo = 3;
Class class = [^{
    int foo1 = foo;
} class];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(class));
```

Why need block in global memory?
What advantage `__NSGlobalBlock__` vs `__NSStackBlock__`?

I read [Block Implementation Specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html), but I don't understand why need `__NSGlobalBlock__` if I create block for only one usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Global` and `Stack` refer to where the captured data resides at the time the block is defined.  If a block is `Global` the runtime knows that no further processing will need to be done.  Things like `copy` become a no-op.  If the block is `Stack`, then the runtime is aware that the data needs to be moved if it will go out of scope before the block is released.  This is especially important for ARC.